# Windows credentials authentication in java based web service

Tags: java

I have java based web service. I want client's windows credentials to be validated in my web application. Here I am not expecting LDAP validation.
How I can validate client's windows credentials in my web application.

Comment: what about ... not. You can have a client send the information to your webservice, but that's a different matter. your webservice accessing local user information, even if possible, would (should) be considered a huge breach in security.

Comment: Active Directory is your option... Not that hard and there are plenty of libraries available.

Comment: @YvanWatchman that's not his option, as he stated: "I am not expecting LDAP validation"

Comment: @Stultuske there is nothing around the windows API... Enterprise applications will have to work with active directory.

Comment: I'm not saying he wouldn't need it, I'm merely stating out he said he would not be using it, and was looking for another way.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your reply.

Comment: Like .Net webservices use IIS or NTML, similarly for java based web services is there anything?